# What are the holes in the records retention laws and regulations regarding US intelligence agencies that make it possible for documents to be deleted?

Tags: united-states, cia, intelligence-service

What are the holes in the records retention laws and regulations regarding US intelligence agencies that make it possible for documents to be deleted?

I am asking, because there might be a historical precedent for the CIA deleting documents that I am not aware of, but I haven't found any credible evidence of such a thing.

Because I found no precedent, I am wondering if there are flaws in how documents are kept that might allow them to delete documents without the public ever knowing about them.

The motivation for this question is that there are still documents pertaining to the assassination of Kennedy that weren't made public, and I was wondering if the CIA could decide to destroy the documents so they're never released publicly or there are mechanisms that prevent anyone from destroying anything.

Comment: If they did, how would we know? Contrarily, it seems quite likely that lots of things get deleted on being read.

Comment: What sort of answer would you be willing to accept? I believe if you tweak your question slightly it may become answerable if what you're interested in learning about is about records retention laws and regulations concerning US intelligence agencies. That information is likely available for research. The quick and easy answer to this is "yes," of course it's _possible_, but that probably wouldn't be very satisfying to you or anyone finding this question later.

Comment: How should I rephrase the question to make it more interesting?